# ui-router not seeing ui-view during attempt to upgrade from angularJS to latest angular

Tags: angular, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have been following the upgrade steps in https://angular.io/guide/upgrade. I removed the ng-app directive and added to my `.ts` entry point file:

`angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['myApp'], { strictDi: true })`

The app loads with no errors, however the main entry route is not rendering any of its views.  The main application template has in it:

`<div ui-view="heading"></div>`

and the "/" route file has:

```
    views: {
      'heading': {
        template: '<p>hello I am a template</p>',
      },
```

The ui-view heading element is empty, but if I add an `onEnter` to that route, it DOES get called.  So the route is being hit, just for some reason it's not finding the ui-view.  Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you you using ui-router hybrid?

https://github.com/ui-router/angular-hybrid